# How to sum the data frames in a list that have the same name?

Tags: r, list, aggregate, tibble

I have two lists containing multiple data frames:

```
list_1 <- list(a = tibble(c(1,2),c(3,4)),
               b = tibble(c(3,4),c(2,5)),
               c = tibble(c(5,62),c(1,6)))

list_2 <- list(a = tibble(c(1,2),c(3,4)),
               b = tibble(c(3,4),c(2,5)),
               d = tibble(c(5,62),c(1,6)))
```

Now, I would like to sum up all data frames that have the same name. Thus, the desired output should look like this:

```
list_1 <- list(a = tibble(c(2,4),c(6,8)),
               b = tibble(c(6,8),c(4,10)))
```

Does any body have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the common names in both the list using `intersect` and add the two list for only the common names with `Map`.

```
common_names <- intersect(names(list_1), names(list_2))
Map(`+`, list_1[common_names],  list_2[common_names])

#$a
#  c(1, 2) c(3, 4)
#1       2       6
#2       4       8

#$b
#  c(3, 4) c(2, 5)
#1       6       4
#2       8      10
```

Same with `purrr`'s `map2` :

```
purrr::map2(list_1[common_names],  list_2[common_names], `+`)
```